# Remove column of N-by-M array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an ndarray of size (54,3) which holds the coordinates of my points as following:

```
array([[ 30., -24., -18.],
   [-26., -20., -20.],
   [ 30., -38.,  30.],
   [ 30., -40.,  30.],
   [ 30., -38.,  50.],
           .
           .
           .
   [-42., -30.,  -8.]])
```

I am trying to remove the Z-coordinate from all the points and result in an (54,2) ndarray, but I cannot make it work.

I am trying with np.delete and np.squeeze but I'm always getting errors. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: ...`arr[:,:2]` or with `np.delete` : `np.delete(arr,2,axis=1)`?

Answer (score 0):

arr[:,0:2] should remove the Z-coordinate